# Sqlite update with min if smaller than existing

Tags: sql, sqlite

Must misunderstand something basic here, have a couple tables:

```
table1 (id, minValue)
table2 (table1Id, value)
```

If I run the query:

```
UPDATE table1 SET minValue = (SELECT MIN(value) FROM table2 WHERE table1.id == table2.table1Id);
```

I get the expected values. However if I run this query the minValues remain null:

```
UPDATE table1 SET minValue = MIN(minValue, (SELECT MIN(value) FROM table2 WHERE table1.id == table2.table1Id));
```

I will be updating the minValue from multiple tables so I want to make sure it stays smaller than the incoming values but still gets updated when minValue is still null.

Comment: I'm not sure if your second query is actually correct. Are you allowed to do `MIN(minValue, (...))` at all? I can confirm that you cannot in MySQL and PostgreSQL. `MIN(column_name)` is a standard SQL aggregate function specification which MUST work with any DB provider (wiling to be corrected)

Comment: Not sure `UPDATE table1 SET minValue = MIN(20, (SELECT MIN(value) FROM table2 WHERE table1.id == table2.table1Id));` runs successfully and updates values as expected though obviously having 20 there is useless. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure that minValue never gets updated to a higher than current value all you need to do is add a condition to only apply the update to rows where there exists a lower incoming value:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET minValue = (
    SELECT MIN(value) 
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1.id = table2.table1Id 
    )
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT value
    FROM table2
    WHERE table1.id = table2.table1Id 
      AND table2.value < table1.minValue
)
```

Comment: Thanks, required one adjustment between WHERE and EXISTS: `WHERE table1. minValue IS NULL OR EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for?

```
UPDATE table1 SET minValue <= ALL(SELECT MIN(table2.value) FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.id == table2.table1Id));
```

Comment: My sqlite program doesn't like `<=` there